# Software to simulate wind tunnel

Tags: windows, java, simulation

I want a software to simulate a wind tunnel (CFD, computational fluid dynamics).

In the software:

1. I must be able to import custom designs like airfoil, tail wing, etc.
2. There must be animation of air flow

Comment: The correct term is CFD. Please search the web and you'll be surprised.

Comment: What license/price is OK?